# getting http response in separate strings

Tags: php, android

I have stored longitude and latitude in database and getting them through http request in the form of a single string. Now I want to start a map activity that takes longitude and latitude from server response and put a marker at that point. The problem is that I can't get how to separate longitude and latitude as they are returned in a single string from server. Here is my activity:

```
public class Signin extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> 
{
  private Context context;
  private TextView roleField;
  private Context context1;

  public Signin(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
  protected void onPreExecute() {}
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try {
      String bus_id = (String) arg0[0];
      String link = "http://mysystem_ip/routes.php?bus_id=" + bus_id + "";
      URL url = new URL(link);
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
      request.setURI(new URI(link));
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
      String line = "";

      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        break;
      }
      in.close();
      return sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    this.roleField.setText(result);
    Intent i1 = new Intent (context, MapsActivity.class);
    i1.putExtra("result",result);
    context.startActivity(i1);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show a sample response?

Comment: Java has plenty of ways to manipulate Strings. You can easily split a large String into multiple parts and parse it out to several different smaller Strings. We would need to see the response String to figure out how you can split it.

Comment: " 31.578369901154527 74.35708886792317" i get a single string from server like this while i want them to be in separate strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to split this String is like this:

```
String response = "31.578369901154527 74.35708886792317";
String[] responseParts = response.split(" ");
String firstPart = responseParts[0];
String secondPart = responseParts[1];
Log.d("SPLIT RESPONSE", "first: "+firstPart+"  second: "+secondPart);
```

This code of course assumes that the delimiter separating the two parts of the string is a blank space `" "` -- As long as that won't change, you should be able to split the response String pretty easily using the code above.

Comment: thanks it worked but as u said it is dirty way so what can be the elegant way

Comment: @shamrozkhan -- Well what I meant by "dirty" is that this is not dynamic in any way. In other words, as long as you are sure your response will always be a single string with two parts separated by a blank space, then it'll work just fine. But if the response is sometimes split by commas or something similar, then obviously a different approach would be needed.